# translating mongo query to C# by using Filter

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

Is there any way to use Filters in C# and translate this mongo query?

```
{'EmailData.Attachments.Files': {$all: [{Name: 'a.txt'},{Name: 'b.txt'},{Name:'c.txt'}], $size: 3}}
```

my data model is like:

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("5f0a9c07b001406068c073c1"), 

"EmailData" : [
    {

        "Attachments" : {

            "Files" : [
                {
                    "Name" : "a.txt" 

                }, 
                {
                    "Name" : "b.txt"
                }, 
                {
                    "Name" : "c.txt"

                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
}
```

I have something like this in my mind:

```
    var Filter =
                Builders<EmailEntity>.Filter.All(s => s.EmailData????);
```

or something like:

```
var Filter =
                Builders<EmailEntity>.Filter.ElemMatch(s => s.EmailData???)
```

I was wondering is there any way in the above filter to use `All` inside ElemMatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty here is that `EmailData.Attachments.Files` is an array within another array so C# compiler will get lost when you try to use Expression Trees.

Thankfully there's another approach when you need to define a field using MongoDB .NET driver. You can take advantage of `StringFieldDefinition<T>` class.

Try:

```
var files = new[] { new FileData(){ Name = "a.txt"}, new FileData() { Name = "b.txt" }, new FileData() { Name = "c.txt" } };

FieldDefinition<EmailEntity> fieldDef = new StringFieldDefinition<EmailEntity>("EmailData.Attachments.Files");

var filter = Builders<EmailEntity>.Filter.And(
                 Builders<EmailEntity>.Filter.All(fieldDef, files),
                 Builders<EmailEntity>.Filter.Size(fieldDef, 3));

var result= collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

Comment: It is very interesting for me to know about StringFieldDefinition, thank you for that.